# AngularJS - Snapping drag

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, draggable

Looking at the guide from AngularJS website (http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/compiler), I have:

```
app.directive('task', function($document){
    return {
        restrict: 'C',
        link: function(scope, element, attr) {
            var startX = 0, startY = 0, x = 0, y = 0;
            element.on('mousedown', function(event) {
                // Prevent default dragging of selected content
                event.preventDefault();
                startX = event.screenX - x;
                startY = event.screenY - y;
                $document.on('mousemove', mousemove);
                $document.on('mouseup', mouseup);
            });

            function mousemove(event) {
                y = event.screenY - startY;
                x = event.screenX - startX;

                element.css({
                    top: y + 'px',
                    left:  x + 'px'
                });

            }

            function mouseup() {
                $document.unbind('mousemove', mousemove);
                $document.unbind('mouseup', mouseup);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

This works fine, except I don't want the smooth dragging feature. Rather, I want to drag the item for say 200px, and then I want it to snap to that position, and then if moved another 200, then snaps back again. How can I do that?

Comment: you can use jquery ui drag and drop, it has a rich api that supports your scenario

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a fixed grid, just apply that to your X and Y coordinates like so:

```
y = event.screenY - startY;
x = event.screenX - startX;
y = y - ( y % gridSizeY );
x = x - ( x % gridSizeX );
```